# Declare a value in Sparksql in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, variable-declaration

I wanted to declare a fixed value before implementing various chunks of queries, and tried the following method. Unfortunately, no values are returned. Any advice will be much appreciated.

```sql
SET end_date = '2022-03-01';

—chunk 1
select * from p 
where p.SEND_DATE between '2022-02-01' AND ${end_date}

—chunk 2
select * from p 
where p.SEND_DATE between '2022-01-01' AND ${end_date}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a [widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets):

```
CREATE WIDGET TEXT end_date DEFAULT '2022-03-01';
```

Then, you can use it in your query with the syntax you have in your question. If you want it to be a DateType instead of a string, then you can turn it into a date with [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#to_date) in your query.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it returned the error: cannot resolve 'CAST(((2022 - 3) - 1) AS DATE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast int to date

Comment: "If you want it to be a DateType instead of a string, then you can turn it into a date with to_date in your query." Use `TO_DATE($end_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd').`